# What PHP/JS specific features does Dreamweaver CS5 have?

Tags: php, dreamweaver, zend-studio

I'm debating on whether to get Dreamweaver CS5 or Zend Studio for my web developing. I was happy with Dreamweaver until I tried Zend Studio (and Netbeans for that matter) and realized what kind of great code formatting and completion I was missing out on.

My question is, does the newest version of Dreamweaver support:

- PHP / JS formatting
- Code completion (including custom classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this will help much b/c I don't know what previous versions of DW had or didn't have. I was using the old Homesite/Coldfusion Studio editor before starting a new job where I had to use DW CS5. For PHP it will help with auto completion of variables, both $_(whatever) type, as well as one's you've previously defined on the page.

DW also checks for things like missing ";" at the end of lines and brackets not being closed correctly when you're doing a bunch of function(calls(inside(other(functions())))).

If you want the WYSIWYG part, it's there, but it's trivial to make it go away and stay on a "code only" view.

Not sure about the JS side as much. I usually debug via Firefox tools.

Hope that helps.

D.